# Using mysqli and rand()

Tags: php, random, mysqli

Trying to create a page where users can create a character with a base, one marking and eye colour. The three descriptions are all stored in seperate tables and are called randomly. I would like to limit the amount of times they are called so the user can't run through them all until finding a combo they like.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['count']))
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;

if($_SESSION['count'] < 5) {
    $_SESSION['count']++;

    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT `base` FROM `bases` WHERE `type` = 'Starter' ORDER BY rand()");
    while($info = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['refreshresultbase'] = $info['base']; 
    }

    $querymark = $mysqli->query("SELECT `marking` FROM `markings` WHERE `type` = 'Starter' ORDER BY rand()");
    while($infomark = $querymark->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['refreshresultmarking'] = $infomark['marking']; 
    }

    $query3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT `colour` FROM `eyes` WHERE `type` = 'Starter' ORDER BY rand()");
    while($infoeye = $query3->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['refreshresulteyes'] = $infoeye['colour'];  
    }
}
?>
```

Still really really new to mysqli so I apologise if this is a simple error.

Comment: log the first 'random' selection, then dont let the user change it.

Comment: And don't use `ORDER BY rand()` on tables with more than a few dozen rows or your performance will nosedive severely.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'log the first random selection' and I know ORDER BY rand () can be slow but luckily I shouldn't have many rows.

Comment: check if $_SESSION['refreshresultmarking'] isset, if so they have already selected one (randomly) so don't let then select again.

Comment: What is the "point" of offering "options", when you limit the user to "3 random" combinations?